# PHP md5() gives different output then MySQL md5

Tags: php, mysql, md5

I'm trying to set up a login system, but I can't solve one problem:
PHP is giving me an other output with md5(); than MySQL...

For example, in PHP:

```
$password = md5("brickmasterj");
return $password;
```

Returns:

```
3aa7b18f304e2e2a088cfd197351cfa8
```

But the MySQL equivalent gives me a shorter version:

```
3aa7b18f304e2e2a08
```

What's the problem? And how do I work with this while checking passwords?

Comment: Are you inserting/updating or selecting the MySQL's MD5 output? I have a feeling this is down to your Column having a width/size of 18 characters only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess the problem in the length of column of your table, set the length of password field to at least 32

Comment: right, you can see that the value from mysql is the beginning of the php generated string and also  it's 18 characters long :)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem, there was a maximum on column length.

Answer (score 2):

No way MySQL returns it of a length of < 32. If you would do a simple query like `SELECT md5('brickmasterj')`, you would see. Now you are most likely inserting the value into a column which is not wide enough.

Answer (score 2):

Is your database field 32 characters long? Are you writing to the database using mysql's md5?

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem, there was a maximum on column length => -1 .... by the way thanks ! you are so pro.

Answer (score 0):

The hash size if always fixed. In your case the hash size is 128 bits. When converted to a ascii string it would be a 32 character string that contains only hexadecimal digits.
so if you are storing variable character the length should be atleast 32 
example:`password varchar(32)`
should go in mysql table then you can call using php  using 
`select password from table where password =md5($password);`