# Login and registration with php and md5

Tags: php, mysql, md5

I'm trying to hash the users password using md5 but I can't log in. It store the password hashed but when I do the login it doesn't work.Why? These are the functions (before I started using md5 it worked)

```
function checkLogin($username, $password)
{
    $password=md5($password);
    $checkLogin = "select * from users where username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $check = mysql_query($checkLogin);
    return mysql_num_rows($check) > 0 ? true : false;
}

function setRegistration($username, $password) {
    $query = "insert into users (username, password) values('$username' , md5('$password'))";

    mysql_query($query)
    or die (mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: MD5 is a hash not an encryption.

Comment: Oh sorry, I only know that md5 is used to store passwords because it's irreversible. So why it doesn't work?

Comment: What is the column definition for `password`?

Comment: password is varchar(10)

Comment: That's your problem. MD5 returns a string of 32 characters. Did you really not compare the actual DB values with the hashed password string to see that one is shorter?

Comment: You are right, and you're on a good path. The only problem is that `md5` hasn't been considered safe since a couple years. You should be using [pbkdf2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php) to generate the hashes to store in the DB, or at the very least `SHA1` if your php version is too old. FYI: md5 length is 32chars... 10 is not enough

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP md5() gives different output then MySQL md5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540744/php-md5-gives-different-output-then-mysql-md5)

Comment: I set varchar(32) but still not working

Comment: Did you register a new user? Did you compare the hashed password in your database with the one you get in `checkLogin()`?

Comment: I bet when password was stored, it was cut off at 10 and after changing your column to 32, you're trying to access a password which still contains a 10 character length. You need to start over and use 50 instead of 32 just to be sure. Shall I convert my comment to an answer? ;-)

Comment: ok, where are we with this? have you not seen my comment there ^^^^^^^^^^^ ?

Comment: No, I'm not so noob aahah I changed the the column, I deleted old user and created a new one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake.

1. Column password was varchar(10) instead of varchar(32) (thank you for telling me that!)
2. When I was trying to resolve the problem I wrote that :

```
$check = $Database->checkLogin($_POST['username'], md5($_POST['password']));
```

and then in the database function

```
function checkLogin($username, $password)
    {
        $password=md5($password);
        $checkLogin = "select * from users where username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $check = mysql_query($checkLogin);
        return mysql_num_rows($check) > 0 ? true : false;
    }
```

So I was basically doing an hash of a already hashed password!

Answer (score 0):

This is because during registration you are converting the password to `MD5` through SQL and during login you are comparing the password converted to `MD5` by php.

That is why they are mismatching I guess this is not the case on all servers.
But sometime It cause problems.

So the better approach is to convert password through `PHP` or by `SQL` during both s`ign_up` and `sign_in`

Because In case of php use may like to add some salt values in their MD5 string

Comment: I used  `function checkLogin($username, $password)
    {
        $password=md5($password);
        $checkLogin = "select * from users where username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $check = mysql_query($checkLogin);
        return mysql_num_rows($check) > 0 ? true : false;
    }

    function setRegistration($username, $password) {
        $password=md5($password);
        $query = "insert into users (username, password) values('$username' , '$password')";

        mysql_query($query)
        or die (mysql_error());

    } ` but it doesn't works

Comment: have you compared the `MD5` string which is getting generated during `checkLogin()` and the password saved in database table

Answer (score -2):

You need to correct your Insert Query like this.

```
$query = "insert into users (username, password) values('$username' , '".md5($pass)."')";
```

Comment: the password it's stored correctly in md5 format! The problem is when I try to log in

Comment: do cross check if MD5 hash stored in DB is the correct one. also check if you have any tailing spaces. In that case you need to trim your input data